# NodeJS v6.9.1 variable in string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Try to learn basic functions from NodeJS, stuck in append String to file with variable:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

var user = os.userInfo();

fs.appendFile('test.txt', 'Hello ${user.username}!');
```

From test.txt I got:

```
Hello ${user.username}!
```

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use back-tick (`) instead of '

```
fs.appendFile('test.txt', `Hello ${user.username}!`);
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (grave accent)
>   character instead of double or single quotes.

Comment: thanks! Now I get it. Also StackOverflow is running in NodeJS mode. :D

Comment: Sorry one more question: what is the origin of the Template Literals? Looks like a javascript thing but I am not sure if it is some new standard from certain library or in general part of javascript syntax.

Comment: @Dreamer template literals editions of the ES2015 / ES6 specification

Comment: @Dreamer I am glad it helped! Make sure to select the answer helpful :)

Comment: @Dreamer For example in Ruby used similar with one difference. In Ruby used `#{}` and in JavaScript `${}`